# Need Guidance. TCPDF error on output

Tags: php, tcpdf, output

I am having an issue with my TCPDF output error and I'm not sure how to solve it. It said

> "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\Printing\listing_p.php:14) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 9043 TCPDF ERROR: Some data
>   has already been output to browser, can't send PDF file"

I'm quite new to TCPDF and it doesn't have proper tutorial to guide me through. Examples dont help much though...

Here is my codes:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>insert page</title></head>
<body>

<?php 

ob_start();

require_once("../tcpdf/tcpdf.php");
require_once("../tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php");
$pdf = & new TCPDF("P","mm","A4",true,"UTF-8",false);

$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false);

$link = mysql_connect("localhost","root");
if(!$link){
    die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());
}

if(mysql_select_db("New_People",$link)){
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM People1");

$pdf->SetMargins(15,20,15);

$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('FreeSerif','B',12);
$pdf->SetFillColor(255,255,255);

$i = 0;
$max = 30;
$row_height = 5;
$backup_group = "";

$pdf->Cell(60,$row_height,'Id',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(60,$row_height,'Code',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(60,$row_height,'Name',1,0,'C',1);


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $Id = $row['P_Id'];
    $Code = $row['P_Code'];
    $Name = $row['P_Name'];

    if($backup_group != $Id)
    {
        $pdf->SetFont('FreeSerif','B',12);
        $pdf->Cell(120,$row_height,$Id,1,1,'C',1);
    }

    if($i >$max){

        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->SetFont('FreeSerif','B',12);
        $pdf->SetFillColor(255,255,255);

        $pdf->Cell(60,$row_height,'Id',1,0,'C',1);
        $pdf->Cell(60,$row_height,'Code',1,0,'C',1);
        $pdf->Cell(60,$row_height,'Name',1,0,'C',1);

    }

    if(!empty($group)){
        $pdf->SetFont('FreeSerif','',12);
        $pdf->Cell(60,$row_height,$Id,1,0,'C',1);
        $pdf->Cell(60,$row_height,$Code,1,0,'C',1);
        $pdf->Cell(60,$row_height,$Name,1,0,'C',1);
    }

    $backup_group = $Id;
    $i++;

}

mysql_close($link);
ob_end_clean();
$pdf->Output('mypdf.pdf','I');

}
else{
die("Error: ".mysql_error());
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestion or help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved, just removed

> require_once("../tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php");

from the top of the codes then everything is going well.